Tink is preferring to use AWS KMS system instead of Android keystore to storing keys
I am new to Tink and have a question as to why Tink is preferring external KMS like AWS KMS instead of using native Android Keystore.
There could be use cases where we don`t want to take keys outside the app/device.

I'm sure there are use cases where you would want your keys next to your application, in a file next to it for example. I'll assume you already had the lecture about the security controls needed around your use case.
You can use AndroidKeystoreKmsClient with Tink to use the native Android KMS. I can't test, but this SO answer should get you started.
Tink even supports plaintext keys in a file out of the box. Creating an unencrypted keyset with:
python cleartext_keyset_cli.py --mode generate --keyset_path danger.tink

Will produce the following keyset:

  "primaryKeyId": 686006127,
  "key": [
    {
      "keyData": {
        "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.AesGcmKey",
        "value": "GhCkKaBgscB8+eobbIkIjgRT",
        "keyMaterialType": "SYMMETRIC"
      },
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "keyId": 686006127,
      "outputPrefixType": "TINK"
    }
  ]
}


Will this be good practise to do that in context of securing keys used for encryption ?

No, it's not. I missed the Android tag. I wanted to show that you can use an insecure keystore (a file) if you really have to. I added a link to an Android specific example - sorry I can't test it though...
